# Converting code from PasswordDerivedBytes to Rfc2898DerivedBytes, unicode

Tags: c#, cryptography

I'm attempting to replace PasswordDerivedBytes with Rfc2898DerivedBytes but I'm having a problem with the latter when getting back a unicode encoded result.

Take this code for example:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void DerivedBytesTest()
    {
        string encrypted = "y4Ijqo9Ga/mHlFbLHDdDUkYZlyu7CHF4PVXGLnb8by7FAVtCgPLhFSiA9Et6hDac";
        string key = "{00B3403A-3C29-4f26-A9CC-14C411EA8547}";
        string salt = "gT5M07XB9hHl3l1s";
        string expected = "4552065703414505";
        string decrypted;

        decrypted = Decrypt(encrypted, key, salt, true);
        Assert.IsTrue(decrypted == expected); // Works

        decrypted = Decrypt(encrypted, key, salt, false);
        Assert.IsTrue(decrypted == expected); // Doesn't work, get wrong unicode characters in 24 character string
    }

    private string Decrypt(string encrypted, string key, string salt, bool legacy = false)
    {
        UnicodeEncoding encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();

        byte[] encryptedDataBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted);
        byte[] saltBytes = encoding.GetBytes(salt);

        RijndaelManaged encryption = new RijndaelManaged();
        DeriveBytes secretKey;

        if (legacy)
        {
            secretKey = new PasswordDeriveBytes(key, saltBytes) {IterationCount = 100};
            encryption.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        }
        else
        {
            secretKey = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, saltBytes, 100);
            encryption.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros; // This is the only one that doesn't throw the "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed" exception, but gives me a non-ASCII result
        }

        ICryptoTransform decryptor = encryption.CreateDecryptor(secretKey.GetBytes(32), secretKey.GetBytes(16));

        string decryptedText = "";

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(encryptedDataBytes))
        {
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[encryptedDataBytes.Length];
                int decryptedCount = cryptoStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                decryptedText = encoding.GetString(bytes, 0, decryptedCount);

                if (!legacy)
                {
                    // Something more to do with result?
                }
            }
        }
        return decryptedText;
    }
```

I wonder if anyone can advise where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PasswordDeriveBytes` is a badly implemented extension of PBKDF1, while `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` is the implementation of PBKDF2. Both derive a key from a password, but they are two different algorithms and therefore they derive two different results. As they are using cryptographically secure hashes underneath, there is no way to convert one to another.

If you can spare a few bytes of storage you could still derive the key using PKBDF1 and then encrypt that key using the result of PBKDF2. If the output size is identical you could even use XOR encryption for that (a one-time-pad) but AES would of course also work. So then the decryption becomes: calculate PBKDF2 result, decrypt data key, use data key to decrypt ciphertext.

Otherwise you will have to decrypt and then re-encrypt the result.

---

If you want to compare the decryption result then compare the resulting *bytes*; do not first convert it into a string. Using authenticated encryption or a MAC is highly advised so that a authentication tag can be validated instead. Just ignoring padding exceptions by using Zero Padding is not the way to go. These padding errors occur *because the key is wrong*.

---

Generic notes:

- `PasswordDeriveBytes` should *not* be used for any amount of bytes > 20 bytes as the Mickeysoft extension of PBKDF1 is horribly insecure, even repeating bytes in the output (!). If you do the same for PBKDF2 then any adversary will have to do half the work that you have to do so that's not a good idea either.
- The iteration count in the question is very low, but as you seem to use a highly random UID instead of a password that should be OK.

Comment: Thanks for the response Maartren. Yes I'm trying to move away from PasswordDerivedBytes but have a lot of unit tests that pass on it but not Rfc2898DeriveBytes (a license server all products use). Trying to encode in C++ highlighted that PasswordDerivedBytes was bad/MS only. The solution I've came up with is to decode using both methods and return the different results in a list that are inspected for size (like you say) with the appropriate result used until all clients are switched to Rfc2898DeriveBytes.

Comment: Yep, that would work. You could also try and use a protocol version number to distinguish versions; then you can do the upgrade to other algorithms / parameters without doing size comparisons. And you could also vote up if you find my answer illuminating.